# Python's importlib.invalidate_caches() doesn't seem to work in my case

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program that is misbehaving in python3.11. My program checks at startup if a module exists. If it doesn't it installs it and then runs importlib.invalidate_caches() so that, in theory, the code that follows can just use it. However this doesn't seem to work. If I run my program a second time it discovers the module and doesn't reinstall it and my code works. I will try to lay out some pseudocode below.

My main.py does something like this:

```
if importlib.util.find_spec('thepackage') is None:

    subprocess.run(["python3", "install_the_package.py"])

    # could the problem be a race condition? testing seems like no.
    #import time
    #time.sleep(120)
    
    # This next call is supposed to make it possible for this tool to
    #   immediately use the package but so far I have not got this working.
    
    importlib.invalidate_caches()

# at this point thepackage is installed for sure

import thepackage  # note that this import fails. says it can't find package.
```

now my install_the_package.py looks somewhat like this:

```
command = f"cd /thepackage_dir; 'setup.py install --user --prefix='"
os.system(command)
```

The module uses setuptools/easyinstall as its install process. The module is getting installed exactly where it needs to be.

Again, the install process works because if I run twice in a row the module is not found on the first run but is on the second run.

I wondered if there was some race condition I was running into. But subprocess.run() is supposed to block.

The easyinstall process takes a second or two to complete and I put in a sleep for 2 mins timer in my code at one point and it still can't import the package the first time through.

I noticed that there was a bug in python possibly related to this:

https://bugs.python.org/issue45703

But I have checked that the fix for it (https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ae1965ccb4b1fad63fab40fe8805d1b8247668d3) is in my (3.11.2) python's source code that I am using.

Any ideas what the problem could be? I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: Note that I am using subprocess and python3 to invoke an external program because my real world problem actually calls another program that actually calls the python install. I really can't get around this external install program approach.